# Aggregating point geometries and creating envelope using Virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, spatialite, polygon-creation, virtual-layer

I am trying to group points using a Virtual layer and create a rectangle covering an extents but I cannot get it to return the geometry.

Current code is this:

```sql
SELECT
    VP.Page,
    st_envelope(st_collect(VP.geometry)) AS geometry
FROM
    "Viewpoint Locations" AS VP
GROUP BY
    VP.Page
```

Coordinates are in OSGB

Sample point:

```
wkt_geom    ele name    VP  Easting Northing    Date    Time_Only   Distance    Bearing Page
PointZ (347471.40698287688428536 169679.50496837147511542 20.05986800000000159) 20.059868   632 01  347471.407  169679.505  15/11/2021  12:55:23    630.613 165.476 1
```

Link to file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=101V1qc9KstZ-e9jh-AlUzlT5EAfTkVFf&authuser=gwrichardson%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs

Comment: Interesting I've tried that and the line "Envelope(AddPoint(MakeLine(p.geometry),StartPoint(MakeLine(p.geometry))))" doesn't appear to be recognised a function (ending up as the column header, with null values). I did try adding "AS geometry" to the end of this line but it still ends up with a column of null values

Comment: the query is fine, make sure the CRS is properly set/recognized

Comment: I added the CRS and geometry type in the dialogue - no difference. Or do I need to set it in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting your input data *'Viewpoint Locations.geojson'* I could assume that the visualization issue caused by *How QGIS treats your GeoJSON* (probably because ***"QGIS does not support `GeometryCollection` as a valid geometry type."***).

[image: geojson_text_editor]

> Consult [GeoJSON driver help page](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html) for detailed explanations on options

When I checked the details of your input file it may look absolutely fine.

[image: input]

However, when one try this innocent query over input data, one can get a better understanding that something goes wrong.

```sql
SELECT
    VP.Page,
    st_astext(VP.geometry) AS geomtxt
FROM
     "Viewpoint Locations" AS VP
```

and the Virtual layer will look as following

[image: vl]

As you can see Virtual layer treats each point as `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION()` instead of initial `Point (PointZ)`. Unfortunately, the [`ST_Force2D()`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78142/how-can-i-strip-out-z-values-in-postgis) does not work in Virtual layer.

---

As a workaround you may follow this workflow:

**Step 1.** Use the ["Drop M/Z values"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drop-m-z-values) geoalgorithm

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the same query

```sql
SELECT
    VP.Page,
    st_envelope(st_collect(VP.geometry)) AS geometry
FROM
    "Viewpoint Locations" AS VP
GROUP BY
    VP.Page
```

and get the following output

[image: result1]

---

IMHO GeoJSON is not yet in the ideal "relationship" with QGIS. See for instance this thread: [Merging layers with different geometry (PointZ and MultiLineStringZ) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415923/merging-layers-with-different-geometry-pointz-and-multilinestringz-in-qgis).

However, I could use your query to make envelops with my own `Point (PointZ)` layer stored in the shapefile, see image below.

[image: result2]

---

**References:**

- [Opening GeoJSON file with mixed geometries in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/opening-geojson-file-with-mixed-geometries-in-qgis)
- [QGIS does not show the Geometry Collection Polygons from JSON file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238354/qgis-does-not-show-the-geometry-collection-polygons-from-json-file)